# ZFS Unmount Entire Pool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, zfs, zfsonlinux

I'm getting issues when mounting my zpool.  Some zfs aren't mounting because "directory exists", aka the subfolders that the subdataset is stored in.  Such as `tank/media/movies`.  It says that that `/tank/media/movies` exists, so the mount fails.  So to safely delete all these directories, I want to unmount all zfs file systems.

But zfs doesn't have a recursive unmount option.  So I was just going to run a 1-liner.

```
zfs list -o name | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo zfs unmount
```

But I get the error `too many arguments`.  I think it's because it's printing them all on one line.  Cause when I do the same, but instead of `sudo zfs unmount` I do `echo` instead, it echos it all on one line.

How can I unmount all zfs file systems?

Answer (score 3):

Use `zpool export` instead. It makes sure that *nothing* in the pool is currently being referenced, giving the maximum safety for the deletion you want to run.